# timedelta between 2 input Fields

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, time

first of all thanks for your time. A basic reservation system
I need to input 2 dates (2 fields on models) and get the difference between them, then it should output this difference, in days multiplied by a constant if less then 3 or other constant if more than it. I've tried a lot of questions from here and read the datetime and timedelta doc but im not getting succes with timedelta.

Those are my models:

```
class Visitante(models.Model):
    Nome = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    Data1 = models.DateField(blank=True)
    Data2= models.DateField(blank=True)
    RG = models.CharField(max_length=9)
```

and those are my views:

```
from .models import Cliente, Visitante
from django.views import generic
from django import forms
from django.views.generic import View
from django.forms import ModelForm
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


class IndexView (generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index2.html'


class DetailView (generic.DetailView):
    model = Cliente
    template_name = 'detail.html'

    def reserv (request):
        d1= Visitante.Data1
        d2= Visitante.Data2
        delta = d1 - d2
        delta.days
        return render(request, 'reserv-form.html', {
            'date': delta
            })
```

then im getting this error:

> TypeError at /reservas/reserv-form/ unsupported operand type(s) for -:
>   'DeferredAttribute' and 'DeferredAttribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the model class, rather than an instance of the model to try to access the fields. You should get the instance by performing some query, for example `Visitante.objects.filter(...).first()`. You might also get an instance while creating a new model using a CreateView.

It might help to explore these things in the Django shell `python manage.py shell` for faster feedback.

Comment: i swear to god that im trying everything. should i create an object for each date?

im getting unsuportted opperand types for-: str and str

Comment: hard to debug such a message without the code that causes it... Did you try in the django shell? Can you update your question with the bit causing the error?